# Ajax / JQuery - Selecionar / marcar um option disabled automaticamente

Tags: jquery, ajax, select

Fala galera!

É o seguinte, tenho uma página dinâmica onde os elementos dos selects são carregados via Ajax conforme os elementos selecionados anteriormente em outros selects, tipo, por exemplo, quando seleciona a Cidade em um select e a combo de município carrega os municípios da cidade selecionada anteriormente, enfim...

Está tudo funcionando perfeitamente, porém tem um select que ele tem valores fixos, ou seja, são carregados via Ajax, porém os valores nunca mudam, o que muda é o option selecionado, o option deve ser selecionado (ter o selected) automaticamente de acordo com o que foi selecionado nas combos anteriores.

Isso ele hoje já faz, porém como a combo não está bloqueada o usuário tem a opção de escolher outro option que não está de acordo com as informações passadas nas outras combos, então eu coloquei um código jquery para bloquear esse select ($('#iddocampo').prop('disabled', true)), ai ele fica block, porém agora ele não consegue mais marcar/selecionar o option correto quando está bloqueado.

Resumindo, quando o select está desbloquado, ele marca/seleciona o option certo de acordo com os parâmetros selecionados nos outros combos/selects, porém quando este select está bloqueado ele não consegue marcar/selecionar o option certo, sempre fica marcado o primeiro option do select.

Alguém sabe porque isso acontece? Alguma luz?

Aguardo a ajuda de vocês!!!

Comment: Podes mostrar o código que muda esse select?

Comment: É possivel mudar um select mesmo estando disabled: https://jsfiddle.net/f9gnryqb/ - podes explicar melhor o teu problema? se quiseres adapta o jsFiddle para mostrar o teu problema

Comment: Olá Sérgio.Então, está um pouco mais difícil do que parece por que o html é todo carregado dinamicamente. O trecho de código que carrega esse select em específico é esse:

Comment: Gabriela, junta na pergunta que eu ajudo a formatar. Clica em [edit]...

Comment: Gabriela, podes juntar um exemplo de HTML? ou um jsFiddle com um exemplo?

Comment: Sim Sérgio, amanhã vou tentar detalhar melhor...Mas o que eu quero é exatamente como você postou ai, só que ele não pode estar disabled pois senão não entra no submit....

Comment: Podes ter assim disabled e depois ter um input[type="hidden"] que guarde o valor...

Comment: Eu posso ter um hidden com o mesmo id do select?

Comment: Não. Mas há maneiras de resolver isso. Vendo o HTML fica mais fácil de dar sugestões.

Comment: O pior Sérgio é que não tem html..rsrs...Todo o código é gerado dinamicamente....Você conhece o OTRS? É nele que estou mexendo...

Answer (score 0):

Olá, passei por algo parecido, creio que possa ser isso: Substitua o `disabled`  por `readonly`. Creio que com isso funcione =)

Comment: Raylan, o readonly não funciona no select, ele não bloqueia o campo.

Comment: Humm, pior que é... será que não da pra vc substituir os selects que não podem ser alterados por inputs? aí vc colocaria o readonly e resolveria. ele vai continuar mostrando o valor e não será alterável.

Comment: Então, não dá..tem que continuar com o select. Você conhece o OTRS? É nele que estou mexendo, os campos são criados dinamicamente, é bem chatinho de mexer nele, é feito em perl, enfim. Então eu só queria deixar esse select fixo, não dando a opção do usuário alterar...

Comment: poxa infelizmente não tenho conhecimento =/